# EXC_BAD_ACCESS just crash on arm64 when run nestopia project with xcode 7

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access, istream, arm64

The nestopia project url:https://github.com/jzdziarski/nestopia
When I download and run it on an 32bit iOS Device, it works well.(not include arm64).
But when I run it on arm64 IOS Device, it crashes :EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

It crashes at this point:

```
void In::SafeRead(byte* data,dword size) {
    static_cast<std::istream*>(stream)->read( reinterpret_cast<char*>(data), size);
}
```

Without any console output and with EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0xffffffff00000000)

Then,I try to set Libstd++,GNU98... and run on arm64, it crash, it say

> :stack overflow detected(not EXC_BAD_ACCESS).

Please help me!

Comment: EXC_BAD_ACCESS error throw when you try to access unallocated memory address. First debug which statement caused this error.

Comment: But run 32 bit (not include arm64) is well. and run arm 64,it crash.Can you run the project?download source code:https://github.com/jzdziarski/nestopia

Comment: It's the nes emulator.You just add *.nes game,and run it.

Comment: Well, yes; the world is full of buggy code which implicitly assumes everything is 32-bit and breaks in weird and wonderful ways on 64-bit machines. If you really want _somebody else_ to sit down and start debugging an entire project with barely any information to go on, then file a bug against the project - that's a work request, not a programming question.